# Reescribir una linea en un archivo.txt Java

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo un archivo txt con unos datos:

```
Datos
Juan-123
----
Pedro-456
----
Jose-789
----
```

Y quiero buscar en el archivo la linea igual a `Pedro-456` y reescribir los numeros `456` de esta por `0022`, Sin alterar el contenido de las otras lineas. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```java
File ArchivoUsuarios = new File("ArchivoUsuarios.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(ArchivoUsuarios);
        BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
          String User = Pedro;
          String ActPassword = 456;
          String NewPassword = 0022;
          String Wanted = User + "-" + ActPassword;
        try {
             while(Reader.readLine() != null){
                 String Aux = Reader.readLine();
                 String input = "";
                 if(Aux != null){
                     if (Aux.equals(Wanted)){
                         input += Aux.replace(ActPassword,NewPassword);
                         FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ArchivoUsuarios);
                         fileOut.write(input.getBytes());
                         fileOut.close();
                     }
                 }
             }        
        }catch (IOException ex) {}
```

El problema es que con este codigo me borra todo el contenido del archivo y me deja escrito unicamente el nuevo `Pedro-0022`, Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Te deja solo la linea que modificas porque en el if le indicas que solo tomes esa linea, deberias agregar que en caso que no sea la linea a modificar la tome tal cual como esta y la agregas al archivo final

Comment: @juandej18 Te refieres a poner un `else` donde en lugar de ser `fileOut.write(input.getBytes());` sea `fileOut.write(Aux.getBytes())`?

Comment: Si de esa manera estaras escribiendo las lineas que no deseas modificar tambien en el archivo. Pero tambien deberias declarar el FileOutputStream fuera del while para asi escribir todo el contenido

Comment: @juandej18 dice lo correcto, estas solo escribiendo una linea en el archivo, porque escribe cuando se cumple la condición, dentro del if, debes concatenar las otras lineas y al final fuera del while escribir el archivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenas las lineas recorridas en un variable de salida dentro del `While`, cuando finalice de recorrer las lineas el String final sera escrito en el archivo con `File.write`.

```
   File ArchivoUsuarios = new File("file.txt");
   FileReader fr = new FileReader(ArchivoUsuarios);
   BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
   String User = "Pedro";
   String ActPassword = 456;
   String NewPassword = 0022;
   String ln = "\n";
   String Wanted = User + "-" + ActPassword;
   try {
        StringBuilder Output = new StringBuilder() // equivale a String Output = ""; pero con mejor rendimiento
        while(Reader.readLine() != null ){
            String linea = Reader.readLine(); 
            if(linea != null && ){
                if (Aux.equals(Wanted)) {
                    Output.append(Aux.replace(ActPassword,NewPassword) + ln)
                } else {
                    Output.append(linea + ln);
                }
            } 
        } // end while
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ArchivoUsuarios);
        fileOut.write(Output.toString().getBytes());
        fileOut.close();
   }        
   catch (IOException ex) {

   }
```

Comment: Solo le cambiaría acumular en un StringBuilder y que luego de cada línea abría que agregar el salto de línea \n

Comment: Gracias @juandej18 agregue la modificación con la variable ```ln```, la del StringBuilder pues no se como se implementarlo, deja el ejemplo  o link y lo actualizo si es mejor.

Comment: Recomiendo el uso de StringBuilder porque cada vez que se concatena un String este no lo agrega al mismo objeto sino que se crea uno nuevo https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=961:stringbuffer-stringbuilder-java-ejemplo-diferencias-entre-clases-criterios-para-elegir-metodos-cu00914c&catid=58&Itemid=180